# dbHasCompleted always returns TRUE

Tags: sql-server, r, jdbc, sql-server-2008-r2, rjdbc

I'm using R to do a statistical analysis on a SQL Server 2008 R2 database. My database client (aka driver) is JDBC and thereby I'm using RJDBC package.

My query is pretty simple and I'm sure that query would return a lot of rows (about 2 million rows).

```
SELECT * FROM [maindb].[dbo].[users]
```

My R script is as follows.

```
library(RJDBC);

javaPackageName <- "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
clientJarFile <- "/home/abforce/mystuff/sqljdbc_3.0/enu/sqljdbc4.jar";
driver <- JDBC(javaPackageName, clientJarFile);
conn <- dbConnect(driver, "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.56.101", "username", "password");

query <- "SELECT * FROM [maindb].[dbo].[users]";
result <- dbSendQuery(conn, query);
dbHasCompleted(result)
```

In the codes above, the last line always returns `TRUE`. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact of function `dbHasCompleted` always returning `TRUE` seems to be a known issue as I've found other places in the Internet where people were struggling with this issue.

So, I came with a workaround. Instead of function `dbHasCompleted`, we can use conditional statement `nrow(result) == 0`.

For example:

```
result <- dbSendQuery(conn, query);
repeat {
    chunk <- dbFetch(result, n = 10);
    if(nrow(chunk) == 0){
        break;
    } 
    # Do something with 'chunk';
}
dbClearResult(result);
```

Comment: As of Feb 2020, this is still an open issue: https://github.com/s-u/RJDBC/issues/73